# Why does my Atari Gym observation take so long to load into CUDA and run on my GPU?

Tags: python, pytorch, openai-gym

I'm wondering why every new observation of my Pong gym environment takes so long to load onto my GPU.

I am attempting to train a Policy Gradient model to play Pong. I have included my entire code below for this model, but my question is about why it takes so long to load and process the matrices on CUDA. The Atari, Pong gym environment cannot run on CUDA as far as I know, so I am converting Numpy arrays to Pytorch tensors at each reset observation and each step observation.
The observation of the Pong screen is 6400 pixels, or an 80 x 80 tensor.

The code below is my adaptation of [this code](http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/), which is purely in Numpy and Python. THIS NUMPY VERSION RUNS FASTER ON MY CPU THAN MY CODE, which I attempted to rewrite for Pytorch to run on my GPU. I'm not posting to ask if I adapted every part of the original code well. I am only posting to ask why the tensors and model are so slow to get on CUDA and to run on CUDA.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.distributions.categorical import Categorical
from torch.optim import Adam
import numpy as np
import random
import time
import gym
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box
device = torch.device("cuda:3" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# hyperparameters
H = 200 # number of hidden layer neurons
batch_size = 10 # every how many episodes to do a param update?
learning_rate = 1e-4
gamma = 0.99 # discount factor for reward
decay_rate = 0.99 # decay factor for RMSProp leaky sum of grad^2
resume = False # resume from previous checkpoint?
render = False

def mlp(sizes, activation=nn.Tanh, output_activation=nn.Identity):
    # Build a feedforward neural network.
    layers = []
    for j in range(len(sizes)-1):
        act = activation if j < len(sizes)-2 else output_activation
        layers += [nn.Linear(sizes[j], sizes[j+1]), act()]
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)

def reward_to_go(rews):
    n = len(rews)
    rtgs = np.zeros_like(rews)
    for i in reversed(range(n)):
        rtgs[i] = rews[i] + (rtgs[i+1] if i+1 < n else 0)
    discounted_r = np.zeros_like(rtgs)
    running_add = 0
    for t in reversed(range(0, rtgs.size)):
        if rtgs[t] != 0: running_add = 0 # reset the sum, since this was a game boundary (pong specific!)
        running_add = running_add * gamma + rtgs[t]
        discounted_r[t] = running_add
    
    discounted_epr = discounted_r.copy()
    discounted_epr -= np.mean(discounted_epr)
    discounted_epr /= np.std(discounted_epr)
    return discounted_epr

from ale_py import ALEInterface
ale = ALEInterface()
from ale_py.roms import Pong
ale.loadROM(Pong)
env = gym.make("ALE/Pong-v5")

lr=1e-2
epochs=50
batch_size=5000
render=False

# make environment, check spaces, get obs / act dims
assert isinstance(env.observation_space, Box), \
    "This example only works for envs with continuous state spaces."
assert isinstance(env.action_space, Discrete), \
    "This example only works for envs with discrete action spaces."

obs_dim = env.observation_space.shape[0]
n_acts = env.action_space.n

# make core of policy network
logits_net = mlp([6400, 3200, 1600, 2]).cuda(device)

def prepro(I):
    I = I[35:195] # crop
    I = I[::2,::2,0] # downsample by factor of 2
    I[I == 144] = 0 # erase background (background type 1)
    I[I == 109] = 0 # erase background (background type 2)
    I[I != 0] = 1 # everything else (paddles, ball) just set to 1
    return I.ravel()

# make function to compute action distribution
def get_policy(obs):
    logits = logits_net(obs)
    return Categorical(logits=logits)

# make action selection function (outputs int actions, sampled from policy)
def get_action(obs):
    return get_policy(obs).sample().item()

# make loss function whose gradient, for the right data, is policy gradient
def compute_loss(obs, act, weights):
    logp = get_policy(obs).log_prob(act)
    return -(logp * weights).mean()

# make optimizer
optimizer = Adam(logits_net.parameters(), lr=lr)

# for training policy
def train_one_epoch():
    prev_x = None
    # make some empty lists for logging.
    batch_obs = []          # for observations
    batch_acts = []         # for actions
    batch_weights = []      # for reward-to-go weighting in policy gradient
    batch_rets = []         # for measuring episode returns
    batch_lens = []         # for measuring episode lengths

    # reset episode-specific variables
    obs = env.reset()       # first obs comes from starting distribution
    done = False            # signal from environment that episode is over
    ep_rews = []            # list for rewards accrued throughout ep

    # render first episode of each epoch
    finished_rendering_this_epoch = False

    # collect experience by acting in the environment with current policy
    while True:
        # preprocess the observation, set input to network to be difference image
        cur_x = prepro(torch.as_tensor(obs, dtype=torch.float32, device=device))
        x = cur_x - prev_x if prev_x is not None else np.zeros(6400)
        prev_x = cur_x
        act = get_action(torch.as_tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32, device=device))

        # rendering
        if (not finished_rendering_this_epoch) and render:
            env.render()

        # save obs
        batch_obs.append(obs.copy())
        

        # act in the environment
        obs, rew, done, _ = env.step(act)

        cur_x = prepro(torch.as_tensor(obs, dtype=torch.float32, device=device))
        x = cur_x - prev_x
        prev_x = cur_x
        act = get_action(torch.as_tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32, device=device))

        # save action, reward
        batch_acts.append(act)
        ep_rews.append(rew)
        
        if done:
            print("done one")
            # if episode is over, record info about episode
            ep_ret, ep_len = sum(ep_rews), len(ep_rews)
            batch_rets.append(ep_ret)
            batch_lens.append(ep_len)

            # the weight for each logprob(a_t|s_t) is reward-to-go from t
            batch_weights += list(reward_to_go(ep_rews))

            # reset episode-specific variables
            obs, done, ep_rews = env.reset(), False, []

            # won't render again this epoch
            finished_rendering_this_epoch = True

            # end experience loop if we have enough of it
            if len(batch_obs) > batch_size:
                break

    # take a single policy gradient update step
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    batch_loss = compute_loss(obs=torch.as_tensor(batch_obs, dtype=torch.float32),
                              act=torch.as_tensor(batch_acts, dtype=torch.int32),
                              weights=torch.as_tensor(batch_weights, dtype=torch.float32)
                              )
    batch_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    return batch_loss, batch_rets, batch_lens

# training loop
for i in range(1):
    batch_loss, batch_rets, batch_lens = train_one_epoch()
    print('epoch: %3d \t loss: %.3f \t return: %.3f \t ep_len: %.3f'%
            (i, batch_loss, np.mean(batch_rets), np.mean(batch_lens)))
```